# Idris proof with simplification causing "type mismatch" error

Tags: proof, idris

I am learning Idris by following along with this book: https://idris-hackers.github.io/software-foundations/pdf/sf-idris-2018.pdf

I kind of hit a snag when getting to the section on proof with simplification (yes it is right at the start).  The small bit of code I am working on is:

```
namespace Numbers

  data Nat : Type where
    Zero : Numbers.Nat
    Successor : Numbers.Nat -> Numbers.Nat

  plus : Numbers.Nat -> Numbers.Nat -> Numbers.Nat
  plus Zero b = b
  plus (Successor a) b = Successor(plus a b)
```

These simpler proofs work okay:

```
One : Numbers.Nat
One = Successor Zero

Two : Numbers.Nat
Two = Successor One

Three : Numbers.Nat
Three = Successor Two

proofOnePlusZero : plus One Zero = One
proofOnePlusZero = Refl

proofOnePlusZero' : plus Zero One = One
proofOnePlusZero' = Refl
```

however as I tried to copy in the more complicated proof I get an error

```
-- works
plus_Z_n : (n : Numbers.Nat) -> plus Zero n = n
plus_Z_n n = Refl

-- breaks / errors
plus_Z_n' : (n : Numbers.Nat) -> plus n Zero = n
plus_Z_n' n = Refl
```

This is the error

```
When checking right hand side of plus_Z_n' with expected type
        plus n One = Successor n

Type mismatch between
        Successor n = Successor n (Type of Refl)
and
        plus n (Successor Zero) = Successor n (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                Successor n
        and
                plus n (Successor Zero)
```

this is the expected behavior - however the recommendation is that one is able to understand why.  I am at a loss and looking for hints or how to conisder this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Idris just follows the definition (“proof of simplification”). So take `plus Zero n = n`. To simplify this type, the definition of `plus` helps: one branch defines `plus Zero b = b`. So we can replace `plus Zero n` with `n` to get to `n = n`, voilà. On the other hand, if trying to simplify `plus n Zero = n`, none of the branches in the definition of `plus` matches `plus n Zero`. So no replacement can be done and Idris is stuck with `plus n Zero = n`, until you help f.e. by case-splitting on `n`.

---

More precisely, if Idris tries to replace `plus x Zero`, it goes through all of the branches one by one and tries to match them, just as it would evaluate it. If it *could* be matched, it will stop. But only if the branch is equal to `plus x Zero`, it will be replaced. So given:

```
plus : Numbers.Nat -> Numbers.Nat -> Numbers.Nat
plus Zero b = b
plus a Zero = a
plus (Successor a) b = Successor(plus a b)

plus1 : plus n Zero = n
plus1 = Refl
```

This won't compile, because `plus n Zero` *could* be handled by `plus Zero b = b`, depending on what `n` is. But because `n` is not known, Idris already stops here, but does not replace it. So the second branch is not reached.

Comment: I think this was my inlcination following more consideration after originally posting.  I am going to think about this some more to make sure I 100% get it.  Before I get back to "accepting" here (since there is no code to try I want to make sure that it logically holds)

Comment: Maybe defining `plus` with the recursion on the second argument helps understanding, `plus' a Z = a; plus' a (S b) = S (plus a b)`. Then `plus' n Zero = n` will be resolved, but `plus' Zero n = n` not so easily.

Comment: I think I get it.  The remaining quesiton is if I add a third case to the definition of plus:  `plus a Zero = a` the second proof still doesnt pass.  I realize this is less than ideal coding style - but just trying to fully comprehend what is going on here.  Wouldn't that be able to perform the replacement.

Comment: Ah, good question. I edited the answer to extend on that bit.

Comment: Thank you - its official I get it (at least at some level).